# Setting http response header from AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

My API Gateway/Lambda setup returns an HTTP response header:
Lambda uses callback function to return the value as part of a JSON
and the *Integration Response* maps it into a HTTP header (using `integration.response.body`)

With this solution, the values are sent back both in the body and the header.

How can I map headers from the Lambda response without duplicating the values in the response body?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you have **Lambda proxy integration** enabled, you can set the response headers as part of Lambda output and API Gateway will return them as part of the HTTP response to the client.

Node.js example:

```
callback(null, {
    "isBase64Encoded": false, // Set to `true` for binary support.
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "header1Name": "header1Value",
        "header2Name": "header2Value",
    },
    "body": "...",
});
```

where `headers` can be *null* or unspecified if no extra response headers are to be returned.

See [Output Format of a Lambda Function for Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Output Format of a Lambda Function for Proxy Integration should go here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html?shortFooter=true#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format

Comment: @StudentsTea: Looks like the link has been recently changed. Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Do JSON.stringify(body)

Answer (score 15):

and, if you **DON'T** have **Lamba proxy integration** enabled, you can add (and map) the response headers in the amazon API gateway console:

go to resources -> method execution -> method response -> add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' (or whatever) header for http status 200. Then go back to method execution -> integration response -> http status 200 -> set header mapping for 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to '*' (or whatever).

Solved this error...: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Comment: what if I want to add an HSTS response header and other security headers to all functions and all response codes?

Answer (score 3):

Since the question states that custom mappings are being used (using integration.response.body), it means Lambda Proxy Integrations are **NOT** being used. So, the solution, in this case, is to map the headers the way you are already doing.

To remove the headers duplication from the body part, use **mapping template** in the integration response and ignore headers in the mapping. I think you might be using pass through responses, that's why you are seeing duplicate headers.

See more documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html