# C# Web API to return as application/json with AWS lambda/gateway

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Using .net core c#

I have a simple api controller as:

```
 public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
 {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]

        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };            
        }
  }
```

There is not much into my startup file of the app.

I am using AWS to deploy this. The issue is when this deployed an is behind API gateway this runs and returns content type as:

```
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
```

But when this is behind our lambda and ELB then this returns us as:

```
Content-Type →application/octet-stream
```

We are not sure whats is the solution here. There is nothing in my code that would make it return like above.

I even tried decorating my controller as:

```
 [Produces("application/json")]
```

But still does not work.
Not sure if we have to make any code changes or any configuration changes that we are not aware of.

Anyone has any inputs?

Comment: Im not sure, but seems like lambda is configured to set specific response header to octet-stream. Try to look at AWS configuration. Maybe this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43190935/setting-http-response-header-from-aws-lambda

Comment: @eocron Do you know how can I specifically add headers to my lambda

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you. Im not that familliar with this technology.