# Headers in node.js lambda not getting set

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a simple Node.JS lambda which looks like this:

```
module.exports = async ({ req, utils }) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      foo: "bar"
    },
    body: "hello"
  };
});
```

It's setup to be called via a URL, so it goes through API Gateway (set to Lambda proxy). When I hit that URL I can see the correct body response but the custom headers are non-existant.

I thought maybe API Gateway is stripping them out or something, so I executed the Lambda via API Gateway..

```
Fri Jun 14 16:25:52 UTC 2019 : Starting execution for request: 13bd0dc7-8ec1-11e9-853f-a52b9bf360d6
Fri Jun 14 16:25:52 UTC 2019 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /track
Fri Jun 14 16:25:52 UTC 2019 : Method request path: {}
Fri Jun 14 16:25:52 UTC 2019 : Method request query string: {}
Fri Jun 14 16:25:52 UTC 2019 : Method request headers: {}
Fri Jun 14 16:25:52 UTC 2019 : Method request body before transformations: 
Fri Jun 14 16:25:52 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=13bd0dc7-8ec1-11e9-853f-a52b9bf360d6, Authorization=************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************b35dc2, X-Amz-Date=20190614T162552Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=eus1xpfhe4, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:062996805340:eus1xpfhe4/test-invoke-stage/GET/track, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_eus1xpfhe4, X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMj//////////wEaCWV1LXdlc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCKh6FFu3duNK7z1dv4SYc+caB0P1dOM75UrjhkjnrApgIgfRSCzXisBuGtn9dSig7QDTPZ6xGL+LL6SyA3sGIAMyAq4wMI8f//////////ARAAGgw2MzExNDQwMDIwOTkiDHQ5JmnY3dq4QglpBCq3A1qg7BjxNgcFxlDIr72sxDQFixgdhM+DUh6gOp3MGnao24FBd7mQVNH7jcd2hzsOTpA2TQSZFtpUCY+0TSHZqAumfodN9k4tywe5uPqFora1e7zTXadG6CcRFYf/XkULirU8yirZ7ct [TRUNCATED]
Fri Jun 14 16:25:52 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"resource":"/track","path":"/track","httpMethod":"GET","headers":null,"multiValueHeaders":null,"queryStringParameters":null,"multiValueQueryStringParameters":null,"pathParameters":null,"stageVariables":null,"requestContext":{"path":"/track","accountId":"062996805340","resourceId":"hzxltu","stage":"test-invoke-stage","domainPrefix":"testPrefix","requestId":"13bd0dc7-8ec1-11e9-853f-a52b9bf360d6","identity":{"cognitoIdentityPoolId":null,"cognitoIdentityId":null,"apiKey":"test-invoke-api-key","principalOrgId":null,"cognitoAuthenticationType":null,"userArn":"arn:aws:iam::062996805340:user/richard","apiKeyId":"test-invoke-api-key-id","userAgent":"aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.11.563 Linux/4.9.137-0.1.ac.218.74.329.metal1.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.212-b03 java/1.8.0_212 vendor/Oracle_Corporation","accountId":"062996805340","caller":"AIDAJ44A63SBN65HTZQRC","sourceIp":"test-invoke-source-ip","accessKey":"ASIAQ5KXG63OHN7V2FAY","cognitoAuthenticationProvider":null," [TRUNCATED]
Fri Jun 14 16:25:52 UTC 2019 : Sending request to https://lambda.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:062996805340:function:analytics-api-development-track/invocations
Fri Jun 14 16:25:53 UTC 2019 : Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 859 ms
Fri Jun 14 16:25:53 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Fri, 14 Jun 2019 16:25:53 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=166, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=910277df-74e9-4c94-bc38-062c112a6c87, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-5d03ca90-488f69c02c1ba617bfcd6963;sampled=0}
Fri Jun 14 16:25:53 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"statusCode":200,"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true","Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"content-type"},"body":"\"\""}
Fri Jun 14 16:25:53 UTC 2019 : Method response body after transformations: ""
Fri Jun 14 16:25:53 UTC 2019 : Method response headers: {Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true, Access-Control-Allow-Headers=content-type, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5d03ca90-488f69c02c1ba617bfcd6963;Sampled=0}
Fri Jun 14 16:25:53 UTC 2019 : Successfully completed execution
Fri Jun 14 16:25:53 UTC 2019 : Method completed with status: 200
```

Response headers:

```
{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true","Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"content-type","X-Amzn-Trace-Id":"Root=1-5d03ca90-488f69c02c1ba617bfcd6963;Sampled=0"}
```

Any tips? I have no idea why the headers are getting stripped out and replaced with access control related ones.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I've now pinned it down to the Lambda instead of API Gateway. Somehow the output from the Lambda is this..

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "content-type"
  },
  "body": "\"hello\""
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43190935/setting-http-response-header-from-aws-lambda

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, it's just describing the output format the Lambda should be if lambda proxy is enabled. The example output in the accepted answer is very similar to the one I have created above

Comment: The fact that API Gateway is returning different headers, and in particular adding CORS headers, makes me think you might not actually be using the `Proxy` integration type. Can you double check that?

Comment: Yep, it's set to Type: LAMBDA_PROXY :(

Comment: Your function parameters look wrong.  There should be 3, Event, Context and Callback.  You should call callback(null,  <object>), and then return nothing to exit the function.  That should correctly set the headers I believe.

Comment: @BParker things are done differently when you use an `async` handler function.  You return the response or a promise that will render the response, and don't use a callback.