# window.fetch() thinks there's a CORS error, Developer Console Network Tab Disagrees

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, fetch-api

I am trying to make an ajax request using `window.fetch()` to an AWS lambda function of mine.

I followed [the AWS Lambda guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) on setting up CORS (and redeployed).

I followed the MDN documentation on [adding headers to `window.fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Examples) to pass in my API key.

My code looks like this:

```
   let myHeaders = new Headers();
   myHeaders.append('x-api-key', lambda_key);
   fetch('https://comically_long_aws_url.com/blah', {
        headers: myHeaders,
    })
    .then((res)=>{
        console.log('success,', res)
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log('err', err);
    });
```

If I look at the network tab, I see that both the OPTIONS and GET request were successful. Indeed, the GET returned the expected information:

**Successful OPTIONS request:**

[image: Network tab for OPTIONS request]

**Successful GET request:**

[image: Network tab for GET request]

**Expected data in GET request response body:**

[image: Preview of response.body]

**Unexpected errors displaying in console:**

[image]

Why is the `window.fetch().catch()` error handler being invoked? Why is there a console error when the network call appears to be successful?

Comment: The CORS headers are in the OPTIONS response but not in the GET. Must be in both

Comment: But why is the data still getting returned?

Comment: Do you mean the client GET headers? So i should add type:cors to the fetch?

Comment: Because server sends it. But browser won't let you access it when headers are missing. It's not server's responsibility to not send the data. CORS is approved/dissaproved by the browser

Comment: As for the headers ...server needs to add the access-control headers to response. Can't do it client side. The most critical one is `access-control-allow-origin`

Comment: That was the issue, plus also ensuring that I put the CORS header in the response of the Lambda function - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47044446/2590119 Would you like to add your comments as an answer so you can get credit and I can "close" this question?